# How can I select records from MSSQL table with multiple SET dependencies?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My table structure/data is this

```
Itemid    RechTyp PstNr  InvoicNr   

1          M       200   Null
2          B       200   84684
3          B       300   84684
4          B       400   84684
5          M       500   Null
6          B       500   84685
7          B       600   84685
8          B       700   84685
```

The column ItemID is unique key. The column PstNr is reference for ItemID 1 & 2
While InvoiceNumber is unique reference for ItemID 2,3 & 4. For every set. The first M and B record is unified by PstNr.

I need a query that can select these 4 records. Bearing in mind that the table contains more than 10,000 records with this sets of records. 
 I am thinking of using cet & Partition functions but I am still working on the query.

My Expected result is: See table below
The Table  MyTransaction , has a status row that is updated for every select statement, hence selecting based on itemID will not work. Becasue I have no gurantee on how the data are inserted. Its possible that ItemId 3 will be in the last row.

```
RechTyp   PstNr    InvioceNr
M       200   Null
B       200   84684
B       300   84684
B       400   84684
```

Comment: your attempt (query) and expected result set might help us to understand the requirement clearly..

Comment: The expected result is to return the first 4 rows. with the column RecTyp, PstNr and InvoicNr. I.e for each select Return a set of [M,B,B,B] [200,200,300,400], [Null, 84684,84684,84684]

Comment: Select * from {whatever the table is called} where id in (1,2,3,4)

Comment: Your expected result set is essentially the whole of the table, based on sample. The question is still not clear, at least not to me. Also, any explanation on what the expected result is, belongs to the post not to a comment.

Comment: @LJ01 this is not that easy, this select query is within a cursor. And row 3 could have a diffrent PstNr eg. 700 and InvoiceNr 84685

Answer (score 2):

This could work well with a low-size table, but may have performance issues in a big records table:

```
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE (Itemid INT, RechTyp NVARCHAR(1), PstNr INT, InvoicNr INT NULL)
INSERT INTO @TEMP VALUES
(1,'M',200,   Null),
(2,'B',200,   84684),
(3,'B',300,   84684),
(4,'B',400,   84684),
(5,'M',500,   Null),
(6,'B',500,   84685),
(7,'B',600,   84685),
(8,'B',700,   84685)

DECLARE @INVOICE INT = 84684

SELECT *
FROM @TEMP
WHERE InvoicNr = @INVOICE
OR PstNr IN (
            SELECT PstNr
            FROM @TEMP
            WHERE InvoicNr = @INVOICE)
```

Output:

```
Itemid  RechTyp PstNr   InvoicNr
1   M   200 NULL
2   B   200 84684
3   B   300 84684
4   B   400 84684
```

Comment: Dear B3S thanks for response. I am not a fan of @Temp table

Comment: That's actually a better answer then mine :-) +1.

Comment: @KingsleySchmid Temp here is used only to store your example data, you dont need it actually :) Ty Zohar

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand the question, you want to get all the records associated with a specific invoice number, and the problem is that one of these records doesn't have a value in it's `InvoiceNr` column, but you can identify it using the `PstNr` column.

I think this should get you your desired results:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT RechTyp, PstNr, InvioceNr
    FROM Table
    WHERE InvioceNr = @InvioceNr
)

SELECT RechTyp, PstNr, InvioceNr
FROM CTE

UNION ALL

SELECT RechTyp, PstNr, InvioceNr
FROM Table
WHERE PstNr IN(SELECT PstNr FROM CTE)

ORDER BY PstNr, InvioceNr
```

Comment: Thanks Zohar  I have already been working towards this direction. That is why I mentioned  "cet & Partition "

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer that work for me. I not a fan of union and join they are more resource intensive.

```
;With cte_get_invoice (ItemID ,RechTyp, InvoicNr, PstNr ,rownumber)
AS
(
SELECT ItemID ,RechTyp, InvoicNr, PstNr, row_number()over(partition by PstNr
                 ORDER BY RechTyp, InvoicNr, PstNr) 
                as rank from  TransactionTable
)

 select  RechTyp, InvoicNr, PstNr FROM TransactionTable
 where PstNr = (select top(1) PstNr from cte_get_invoice where rownumber  > 1 )
 or InvoicNr = (select top(1) InvoicNr from cte_get_invoice where rownumber  > 1 )
```